# C# Removing Submenu Item Image Margins

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, menustrip

See the linked screenshot below.

In short, I need those little white boxes to disappear - they're supposed to house an image, but there is no image, and so I'd rather they disappear.

I've accomplished this using the follow code:

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem menuItem in mnuMain.Items)
   ((ToolStripDropDownMenu)menuItem.DropDown).ShowImageMargin = false;
```

This works for what I guess are the main items, but not the sub-items, as you can see in the picture.

I've tried a few variations on the above code to try and get it to capture everything instead of just the first level items, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

http://i.imgur.com/bst1i4v.png

Comment: You will need to recurse over the items in menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do that for sub items too. To do so, you can use this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetValuesOnSubItems(this.menuStrip1.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList());
}

private void SetValuesOnSubItems(List<ToolStripMenuItem> items)
{
    items.ForEach(item =>
            {
                var dropdown = (ToolStripDropDownMenu)item.DropDown;
                if (dropdown != null)
                {
                    dropdown.ShowImageMargin = false;
                    SetValuesOnSubItems(item.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of above.  Use:

```
    MainMenuStrip.HideImageMargins();
```

Because the recursive method performs the intended manipulation, I used overloading to make it clearer what is intended.  Pattern matching is used because the above sample will throw an exception, not return null.

```
    public static void HideImageMargins([NotNull] this MenuStrip menuStrip)
    {
        HideImageMargins(menuStrip.Items.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList());
    }

    private static void HideImageMargins([NotNull] this List<ToolStripMenuItem> toolStripMenuItems)
    {
        toolStripMenuItems.ForEach(item =>
                      {
                          if (!(item.DropDown is ToolStripDropDownMenu dropdown))
                          {
                              return;
                          }

                          dropdown.ShowImageMargin = false;

                          HideImageMargins(item.DropDownItems.OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>().ToList());
                      });
    }
```